# android Facebook integration fb developer site does not save details

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying this.I go to Facebook developer site, dashboard, and my details set include hash key too.When I add contact email in settings of course I can save it but it does not get saved when I reload it its empty.So I cannot make app public because it says it does not have a contact mail just because it does not allow me to save it. 
Any help or is this a Facebook server issue?

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
    "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        System.out.println("onSuccess");

        String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
            .getToken();
        Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {@Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
            GraphResponse response) {
                Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                try {
                    id = object.getString("id");
                    try {
                        URL profile_pic = new URL(
                            "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
                        Log.i("profile_pic",
                        profile_pic + "");

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    name = object.getString("name");
                    email = object.getString("email");
                    gender = object.getString("gender");
                    birthday = object.getString("birthday");

                    // your SharedPreferences code starts from here.

                    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myprf",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("login", true);
                    editor.putString("name", name);
                    editor.putString("email", email);
                    editor.putString("gender", gender);
                    editor.putString("birthday",birthday);
                    editor.commit();

                    Log.i("name", sharedpreferences.getString("name", ""));
                    Log.i("email", sharedpreferences.getString("email", ""));
                    Log.i("gender", sharedpreferences.getString("gender", ""));
                    Log.i("birthday", sharedpreferences.getString("birthday", ""));

                    // your SharedPreferences code ends here.

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields",
            "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        System.out.println("onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        System.out.println("onError");
        Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: How does this answer OP`s question?